# Singing in an open voice?

Tags: technique, voice

I get complaints that I should sound more open while singing... Now, how much should I open my mouth while singing.Sometimes while implementing this, I have jaw tension, since I did not follow correct opening techniques. What is the exact feeling of singing with an open throat or voice ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**#### Techniques to follow for a proper singing:**

- Firstly, you should be able to put **2-3** fingers inside of your mouth when you sing *vowels*.
- Drop your jaw much more than you do in your daily conversation.
- Open your mouth much wider while you sing and shape it like an **'O'**, lest the sound gets trapped while you sing.
- To practice dropping the jaw - *Massage all the muscles around your face to make sure that they’re free of tension and ready to open.*
- When singing higher notes, open your mouth as if you are yawning so that your vocal cords vibrate which will allow you to sing the higher notes.
- Try yawning and dropping your jaw at the same time.
- Try to stay relaxed while you sing and don't tense up your face.

  ***Here's a tip on [How to Release Jaw Tension.](http://www.purewilrieke.com/how-to-release-jaw-tension/)***

Answer (score 0):

Dropping your jaw is one part of opening up your voice, but it isn't the only part. How does your throat feel when you sing? Is it tight? Do you tense up your throat? Keep your throat relaxed and loose. It may feel like you'll lose control if you do, and it might make you sloppy for awhile, until you're used to it. But once you're used to it, singing as a whole will become easier, and your sound will be more full & open.

Also, how's your breath support? When you need power & breath, are you tightening your throat and/or chest? Or are you powering your sound with your diaphragm? Your diaphragm supplies much more power and can make your voice carry much further than you'd expect.

Imagine that your voice comes from the very pit of your guts. You're not squeezing it out like toothpaste from a tube, but letting it flow out like a water fountain. If you can power your voice from your gut, then you can relax your throat & jaw much more. From there, your voice will open up on its own.